# Key action listener in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I was making a Nokia snake game. I have already made the Frame and everything and already written my algo. Currently I was doing something so that I can perform actions using my keys (such as left, right, up, down).

I made a class named Frame that extends JFrame and implements action listener, somewhere I saw on Stack Overflow that I need to write my code in key released function so as to make my code run while I press the key.

But when I press the keys nothing happened.

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class Frame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 51;
private static final int FRAME_SIZE = 700;
private static final Color SNAKE = Color.GREEN;
private static final Color BOARD = Color.WHITE;
private static final Color FOOD = Color.BLUE;

private static enum DIRECTION {
    right, left, up, down;
}

private static DIRECTION curr = DIRECTION.right;

public Frame() {
    super.setTitle("<<SNAKE GAME>>");
    super.setSize(this.FRAME_SIZE, this.FRAME_SIZE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(this.BOARD_SIZE, this.BOARD_SIZE);
    super.setLayout(layout);
    int val = this.randomNum(this.BOARD_SIZE * this.BOARD_SIZE - 7);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            JButton btn = new JButton();
            super.add(btn);
            this.buttons[i][j] = btn;
            if (i == this.BOARD_SIZE / 2 + 1 && j > this.BOARD_SIZE / 2 - 5 
                 && j <= this.BOARD_SIZE / 2 + 6) {
                this.snakeLL.snake.AddFirst(btn);
                btn.setBackground(this.SNAKE);
            } else if (count == val) {
                btn.setBackground(FOOD);
                count++;
            } else {
                btn.setBackground(this.BOARD);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    super.addKeyListener(this);
    super.setResizable(false);
    super.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyLocation();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        this.curr = DIRECTION.up;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> , somewhere i saw on stack overflow that i need to write my code in key released function so as to.. make my code run while i press the key...

I don't think you got that advice here.

We always advise that you should be using `Key Bindings`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for basic information.

You can also check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) which contains a working example of using `Key Bindings` to animate a component.